# PDO: Calling mysql stored procedure that creates a temporary table and then selecting from it

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is a simplified version of my query:

```
CALL Create_List( 'company' ); SELECT name FROM tmpCompany;
```

Create_List creates a temporary table tmpCompany.

These two statements work correctly when run directly into the database using phpmyadmin but when i call it using PDO in php, I don't get a result.

Is there a specific way of calling stored procedures from php?

**PHP Code**

```
$result = $this->db->prepare( "CALL Create_List( :table ); SELECT name FROM tmpCompany;" );
$result->bindParam( ':table', $this->table );
$result->execute();     
return $result->fetch();
```

**EDIT**

Possibly related?

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38001

Comment: can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do as your current approach of calling a sproc which creates a temp table then selecting from it is a little odd when you could just be calling a sproc and that's it.

Comment: I've got two tables with comma separated fields, so there's no way to compare their items against each other. So the Create_List procedure creates a temporary table that takes the comma separated items into rows. Then we need to select from all rows from that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try breaking the CALL and SELECT into separate statements.